# Does Standard ML support Unicode?

Tags: sml, polyml

Does Standard ML support Unicode?

I believe it does not but cannot find any authoritative documentation for SML stating such.

A yes or no is all that is needed, but you must know for a fact. No guessing or I believe answers. An authoritative link would be better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really. All there is in the standard for the time being is the ability to use `\uXXXX` escapes in character and string literals, and that it does at least *allow* Unicode as the underlying character encoding for `char` or the optional `WideChar.char`. But the standard basis library does not prescribe any support for additional Unicode-aware functionality.

Particular implementations may have additional support, and you may perhaps find some third-party unicode libraries, but that's about it (unfortunately, I have no pointers at hand).

Comment: Atleast [MLton](http://mlton.org/Unicode) currently doesn't fully support unicode. However they claim to be working on it, so somewhere between now and the apocalypse, we might see a new version that supports it :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot what you mean by "Unicode", which is a collection of many standards for many things.  I've not seen any language or system that supports Unicode fully, and I don't even know what that would mean in all details.

You can certainly work with UTF-8 in SML: that encoding was invented to make it easy for ASCII applications to support Unicode.  This might result it better and more efficient representation of Unicode than e.g. UTF-16 seen in Java, which does "support Unicode" officially, but then there are many practical problems with it (like surrogate characters).

With UTF-8 in SML strings, one question is how to work with string literals.  Systems like Poly/ML allow to redefine the ML toplevel pretty printer for `type string`, and it is also feasible to wrap up the compiler to process string literals in a Unicode friendly way.  Both of this is done in Isabelle/ML, which is based on Poly/ML.  So if you take that big theorem proving environment as ML development platform, you have some kind of Unicode support built in (via so-called "Isabelle symbols").

Comment: UTF-8 makes it easy for ASCII *data* to work with a UTF-8 program, and for ASCII applications to not be broken too badly by UTF-8 data. Actually changing any application that assumes ASCII data to work properly with UTF-8 is normally a monstrous task, though, because such applications almost universally assume a fixed character width and UTF-8 has variable-width characters.

Comment: "I've not seen any language or system that supports Unicode fully, and I don't even know what that would mean in all details." - you should check out Swift.